# Warm start for LP (GLOP)

Tags: or-tools

Using `SetHint` does not speed up the solving when using GLOP from or-tools. I also cannot find the support for it in the source.

Short back story: I am solving an integer program using LP as it turns out the relaxed solution can be easily transformed into an acceptable solution.

Is there any LP solver supporting warm start? The problem that I'm solving is stuck in an infeasibility region for long and I believe warm start (since I know a feasible solution) could greatly improve the running time.

EDIT: I believe my problem is very similar to [this question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28846/ways-to-speed-up-solving-an-lp-with-googles-ortools/30020#30020)

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simplexes do not work with values, they work with a basis.
So I am not sure giving hints would help.

Comment: If I solve an easier version of the LP (which has a similar solution to the harder one), then I would hope for the following run (of the harder version) to have near-optimal basis installed, but this does not seem the case. I was unable to find information on this in the docs. Am I doing something wrong, or is this not supported?

Comment: I am not sure that going from values to basis is an easy problem.

Answer (score 0):

CLP supports warm start (https://www.coin-or.org/Doxygen/Clp/classCoinWarmStartBasis.html).
You can call it from or-tools.